# Timestamp data type MilliSeconds Digits in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, sqldatatypes

I have a table dbo.Test in sql server, this table contains 2 columns Id and createdat.

Createdat column data type is datetime2 and it's value contains a date time with 7 digits of milliseconds. (Ex: '2023-08-09 15:44:30.3196369').

I have the same table in Postregsql and the date column data type is timestamp but timestamp accept only 6 digits of milliseconds.

How the date column in Postgresql can accept more than 6 digits in MilliSeconds ?

I tried to use the extension in this link https://github.com/optiver/timestamp9 but it's just implemented to retrieve only the date time with time zone

Comment: *it's just implemented to retrieve only the date time with time zone* - why's that bad?

Comment: Do you actually need fractional seconds out to seven places?

Answer (score 1):

That's 7 digits of *fractional seconds*. MsSQLServer's [`datetime2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime2-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#datetime2-description) holds precision down to **100ns (0.1μs)**, PostgreSQL's [`timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE) is only **1μs**-precise.

> How the date column in Postgresql can accept more than 6 digits in MilliSeconds ?

It *can accept* more, but it'll round off anything beyond the six.

To accommodate the data with full accuracy, you'd have to save the whole thing as a different data type (`bigint`?) representing the number of 0.1μs since epoch, or save the extra precision separately: `timestamp` down to 5 digits (truncate last to avoid rounding), 2 remaining digits as a `smallint`. The former is what [`timestamp9`](https://github.com/optiver/timestamp9) does.