# Postgres loses one digit when saves DateTimeOffset from .Net app (Dapper)

Tags: .net, postgresql, dapper

I create object:

```
{
 id = 123,
 dateTimeOffset = DateTime.UtcNow // 2024-02-27 21:42:43.7125911 +0h
}
```

and save it to postgres db with dapper.
Then I read that object from db with dapper and get

```
2024-02-27 21:42:43.712591 +0h
```

As you could see, value from db is 1 digit shorter than original value.

Why does it happen? And how to fix it.
Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timestamp data type MilliSeconds Digits in Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77264047/timestamp-data-type-milliseconds-digits-in-postgresql) also [Query DateTime Varchar in Nanoseconds level in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78026104/5298879)

Answer (score 2):

The resolution of PostgreSQL's `timestamp` and `time` types is 1 microsecond, as written here in the documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html

Your last digit corresponds to a tenth of a microsecond and therefore gets truncated.